# How do I flip a lens imported from a catalog in Zemax?

Tags: modeling, cad

I am pretty new to this ray tracing software. It is simple to add custom surfaces and insert lenses from a catalog, but I can't figure out how to flip left-right a component without having to modify each surface manually.

This would be useful for instance using plano-concave lenses for collimation to reduce aberrations.

Can someone help me out? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i found out! In Tool>Modify there is a Reverse Element tool that is pretty straight-forward to use.

http://zemax.com/support/knowledgebase/how-to-reverse-an-optical-system

Answer (score 0):

I even use the keyboard shortcut : Select all the surfaces (lines in the description window ) and press Ctrl+B